# Checking and returning Xml from a byte array

Tags: c#, xml

I have a byte array in a C# program.

I want to determine as quickly as possible if the content is Xml. If it's the case, I also want to return the Xml itself.

By now I have this method :

```
    protected bool TryGetXElement(byte[] body, out XElement el)
    {
        el = null;
        // if there is no data, this is not xml :)
        if (body == null || body.Length == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            // Load the data into a memory stream
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(body))
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
                {
                    // if the first character is not <, this can't be xml
                    var firstChar = (char)sr.Peek();
                    if (firstChar != '<')
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // ultimately, we try to parse the XML
                        el = XElement.Load(sr);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // if it failed, we suppose this is not XML
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Is there potential improvement?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Can't you figure out whether it's XML some other way?

Comment: The bytes are coming from a message streams (that I cannot control). I have to route the messages to either of my parsers, depending of the kind of data. Messages are sometimes binaries, sometimes xml.

Comment: Does the structure of the messages you are receiving have any metadata that could clue you in as to their contents (e.g., a MIME header)?

Comment: Is there the possibility of having the xml start with a space?

Comment: @minibill: the XML standard states it must starts with a `<`. Moreover, as it's computer XML, i'm confident it wiki never starts with a sppace

Answer (score 1):

Why not verify if a root node exists rather than check for a '<' ?

```
    public bool GetRootNode(XmlReader reader)
    {
        bool isValid;
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    isValid = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (XmlException x)
        {
            throw new XmlException(x.Message);
        }

        return isValid;
    }
```

You could also use the chain of responsibilities pattern to determine which parser you want to use.

**EDIT**

Not sure if this will work, but here is an example on using the above code:

```
protected bool TryGetXElement(byte[] body, out XElement el)
{
    el = null;
    // if there is no data, this is not xml :)
    if (body == null || body.Length == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        // Load the data into a memory stream
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(body))
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
            {
                XmlReaderSettings settings = XmlReaderSettings { CheckCharacters = true; };
                using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(ms, settings))
                {
                    if (!GetRootNode(reader))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // ultimately, we try to parse the XML
                        el = XElement.Load(sr);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // if it failed, we suppose this is not XML
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see why this would be an enhancement. Your code rely on exception catching (so I do ultimately), while mine check one char. I believe checking a single char is very cheap compared to catching an exception, and can reduce a great number of cases (the probability of having a < char in a non xml string is very low).

Comment: You could have a '<' in a string of html. That is not xml. Does your xml have to fit a particular schema? How are you handling invalid characters that cannot appear in an xml document? Do you have to handle those cases?

Comment: I don't have schema in the sense of XSD files. I have behind the scene a bunch of "parsers" that will analyse the returned XElement. Each parser can handle a well known xml structure. And I also have parsers for non-xml document, but it's another story

Answer (score 1):

Just a few small readability notes:

1. <del>`(body == null || body.Length == 0)` could be [`String.IsNullOrEmpty(body)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx)</del>
2. Longer variable names than `sr`, `el` and `ms` could be a little bit easier to read. "Without proper names, we are constantly decoding and reconstructing the information that should be apparent from reading the code alone." (From [codesparkle's former answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/15939/7076).)
3. The innermost else could be omitted:

   ```
   if (firstChar != '<')
   {
       return false;
   }

   // ultimately, we try to parse the XML
   el = XElement.Load(sr);
   return true;
   ```

Comment: 1. no.... **body** is a byte array not a string. 2. I agree with you at some point. I think I should rename `el` to `foundXElement` or something like this. Other very local variables like `ms` or `sr` can be stay like this. It's a consistent naming convention I use in very small methods. As always, naming convention is subject to developer's feelings. 3. Technically yes, it can be omitted. But I think it's more readable when the two path are visually on the same level. A matter of preference again. Thanks for your feeback anyways.